# Symbolicate crash logs xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I have crash logs and put it in XCode. 
Xcode symbolicate all foundation symbols but not my app:

```
2   UIKit                           0x317fd1a8 -[UITableView   selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:] + 24
3   myApp                           0x0001f084 0x1000 + 123012
4   myApp                           0x0001d6da 0x1000 + 116442
5   myApp                           0x0000643c 0x1000 + 21564
6   myApp                           0x00031dfc 0x1000 + 200188
7   CoreFoundation                  0x355df42e -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46
8   UIKit                           0x317659e4 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56
9   UIKit                           0x3182b3c8 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:]
```

How can I symbolicate my app symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a symbolicatecrash utile (perl script provided with Xcode). And you need .dsym file, it was generated during building you app. For each build you need to have .dsym file (it usually stored somewhere near your output binary).
Also, you may use option "Strip debug symbols during copy" (set it to NO) in your project options to save symbols in your bundle.
Good luck!

Comment: Symbolicatecrash utile do the same result and  "Strip debug symbols during copy" is set to NO. Any ideas?

Comment: Update - use GDB! Move in console to the folder with app and dsym and execute 
`gdb myApp.app`
After that use `p/a 0x0001f084` - crash adress here.

Answer (score 1):

try setting "Deployment Postprocessing" to NO and make sure you're building everything in debug mode